# How do I pass result of asynchronous function to a redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a function which is returning information from an API call,part of which is an access token. I then need to plug that access token into the parameters of a redirect URL. Only problem is that thw redirect is invoked *before* the data is returned. Any ideas on how I can wait till the data is returned before invoking the redirect?

Here's the code:

```
    oauthClient.createToken(req.url)
       .then((authResponse) => {
             oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null,2);
             let newToken = JSON.parse(oauth2_token_json)
             accessToken = newToken.access_token
         })
        .catch((e) => {
             console.error(e);
         });

         res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/?token=${accessToken}`)  
});
```

Comment: Put the `res.redirect` *into* the `then`…

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `.then()` and make sure the previous `.then()` returns the authToken (or any variable). Now run that logic of `res.redirect(..)..` in the next nested `.then()`.

This way you are making sure, the code waits for the asynchronous part to finish off first. then-ables are the best way to make sure your code only runs once the promise is resolved. JavaScript executioner jumps to next line of code once it sees a asynchronous code block, i.e., could be a promise, .then()s, async-awaits.
This was the reason why, `res.redirect()` was running a little earlier.

Comment: Why do you need one more `then`…?!